# MATCH_RECOGNIZE - ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, match-recognize

```
with curse as (select luna,an,valoare from cursl where moneda='eur')

    SELECT *

    FROM curse MATCH_RECOGNIZE (

        ORDER BY an,luna
        MEASURES strt.an as start_an, strt.luna as start_luna,
              strt.valoare as euro_inc,LAST(scade.valoare) as euro_sf,
              count(*) as nr_luni,
              strt.valoare-LAST(scade.valoare) as dif
        ONE ROW PER MATCH
        PATTERN (strt scade{3,})
        DEFINE
            scade AS scade.valoare < PREV(scade.valoare)
        ) a
    ORDER BY a.start_an,a.start_luna;
```

when running this I receive :
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: Which Oracle version?

Comment: Currently I am using Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Oracle-Base](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/pattern-matching-in-oracle-database-12cr1):

> Oracle 12c has added the MATCH_RECOGNIZE clause